# How do I turn off E_INFO in pocketsphinx?

Tags: cmusphinx

E_INFO is printing a bunch of logs. I don't know how I can turn that off. I searched E_INFO from all source files in pocket/base sphinx but I was not able to find where it set up the flag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Configuration option

```
-logfn /dev/null
```

Windows

```
-logfn nul
```

turns off logging.

If you are using API you can also use

```
err_set_logfile(char *filename)
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn it off for the pre-built pocketsphinx, ie in Java at runtime? I tried not to make setRawLogDir call - that didn't help.

Comment: Sorry, Yevgeniy, I'm not sure what your question is about. If it's about Android, sphinxbase there uses standard android logging through logcat, it's a bit different thing.

Comment: It does. Isn't this page's issue about that? Either way, do you know of how I could disable these logs without going through Proguard (which will slow down my build process)? I need to remove these message in debug env

Comment: Yevgeniy, logcat messages could be just filtered out. If you want to completely remove messages from logcat you can edit pocketsphinx sources. I don't recommend you doing that though you'll met issues debugging your application in the future.

Comment: This worked.. For windows Users, use pocketsphinx_continuous -logfn NUL

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the API, this is what I did:

```
// turn off pocketsphinx output
err_set_logfp(NULL);
err_set_debug_level(0);
```

The API given by the accepted answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this did *not* work  for me on Windows 10. I can't find an explicit version but comments suggest my source is younger than July 2015. And the accepted answer did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

i use the API,and add

```
err_set_logfp(NULL);
```

before using

```
ps_init(config);
```

and it will work without any "INFO"log

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
config = Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-logfn','nul')
```